# How to replace a photo uploaded to GitHub with another photo with the same filename?

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I uploaded a photo, 156.jpg to GitHub and then verified it appeared on my website.  Then I changed my mind, and uploaded a different photo, but I used the same name, 156.jpg.  I checked my website again and it continues to show the original photo.  I was thinking the second one would over-write the original one, since it had the same filename.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you're talking about GitHub Pages? Yes, the new file should overwrite the old one, but it can take some time for Pages to generate your new site.

Comment: It’s cached. Just clear your cache will probably solve the problem.

Comment: But I tried the URL in a different browser and it also shows the wrong photo.  So in this case browser caching is not the issue.